# How to merge array of objects keeping data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following two arrays of objects:

**First Array:** `$array1`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100
            [name] => John Doe
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 101
            [name] => Jane Smith
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 102
            [name] => Richard Tea
        )
)
```

**Second Array:** `$array2`

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100
            [age] => 30
            [other] => [other]
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 102
            [age] => 26

        )
)
```

I want to merge these two object arrays and sorted according to `id`.

**Desired output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100
            [name] => John Doe
            [age] => 30
            [other] => [other]
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 101
            [name] => Jane Smith
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 102
            [name] => Richard Tea
            [age] => 26
        )
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the linked duplicate is applicable here - the question is asking how to merge an array of objects, specifically `stdClass` objects, not arrays. Additionally, I believe there is an error in the desired output - `[age] => 26` should be a property of array indexed `1` not `2`?

Comment: Exactly @DarraghEnright. The question isn't duplicate, because I asking how to merge an array of objects, specifically stdClass objects, not arrays. It's similar but not duplicate.

Comment: No problem - I posted an answer below, let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is flagged as a duplicate but I do not believe that it's applicable, since the data in this question are two arrays of `stdClass()` objects.

**Edit**

*My first answer was pretty bone-headed, clearly I had not tested it robustly enough. Thanks to @splash58 who pointed out that I was in fact merging/replacing by array index, not object id. My example only worked because the ordering happened to match in the example data provided. Whoopsy... :)*

So instead, again assuming our arrays of data `$first` and `$second` we can merge the values of `$second` into `$first` with a nested loop and some array/object casting. Finally, we apply a user-defined sort to order the results by id; i.e:

```
foreach ($first as &$o1) {
    foreach ($second as $o2) {
        if ($o1->id === $o2->id) {
            $o1 = (object) array_merge((array) $o1, (array) $o2);
        }
    }
}

usort($first, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->id >= $b->id;
});

print_r($second);
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 100
            [name] => John Doe
            [age] => 30
            [other] => other
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 101
            [name] => Jane Smith
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 102
            [name] => Richard Tea
            [age] => 26
        )

)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: :))) you are merging array by index, but should do by id

Answer (score 1):

You can try it this way with [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

Since your array contents are objects you need to convert them to array when using `array_merge`.

```
<?php

$arrayTemp = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value){
    $arrayTemp[] = (object)array_merge((array)$array2[$key], (array)$value);
}

var_dump($arrayTemp);
?>
```

[Proof of concept]

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(100)
    ["age"]=>
    int(30)
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(101)
    ["age"]=>
    int(40)
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "jane"
  }
}
```